# Excel: Remember window size with multiple windows

Tags: excel, vba

I was able to find the below code at: https://excelribbon.tips.net/T010091_Remembering_Workbook_Position_and_Size.html

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
On Error Resume Next
With ThisWorkbook
    With .Names
        .Add Name:="WinTop", RefersToR1C1:="=1"
        .Add Name:="WinLeft", RefersToR1C1:="=1"
        .Add Name:="WinWidth", RefersToR1C1:="=1"
        .Add Name:="WinHeight", RefersToR1C1:="=1"
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Names("WinTop").RefersTo = ActiveWindow.Top
    .Names("WinLeft").RefersTo = ActiveWindow.Left
    .Names("WinWidth").RefersTo = ActiveWindow.Width
    .Names("WinHeight").RefersTo = ActiveWindow.Height
End With
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
With ThisWorkbook
    ActiveWindow.Top = Val(Mid(.Names("WinTop").RefersTo, 2))
    ActiveWindow.Left = Val(Mid(.Names("WinLeft").RefersTo, 2))
    ActiveWindow.Width = Val(Mid(.Names("WinWidth").RefersTo, 2))
    ActiveWindow.Height = Val(Mid(.Names("WinHeight").RefersTo, 2))
End With
End Sub
```

The code works as expected; however, I need it to do a little more... I have used the "View->New Window" function to display a second tab in another window. How do I save the window position/sizes for both windows?

Comment: How will you be opening these workbooks? is your main workbook opening all other workbooks? maybe with VBA?

Comment: @Zac ... 1 workbook. Just viewing multiple sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `Sheet 1` and `Sheet 2` for your real sheet names as well as `Book1.xlsm` for the file name but KEEP the :1 at the end of the file name.

The original window is Book1.xlsm:1

The second window is Book1.xlsm:2

The third window (if you have one) is Book1.xlsm:3

etc...

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    ActiveWindow.NewWindow
    Sheets("Sheet 1").Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 60
    Application.Left = 863.5
    Application.Top = 1
    Application.Width = 162
    Application.Height = 546
    Windows("Book1.xlsm:1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet 2").Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 50
    Application.Top = 1
    Application.Left = 1
    Application.Width = 862.5
    Application.Height = 546
End Sub
```